# Question about Hibernate POJO class design

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am learning hibernate and have a question regarding the design of my POJO class
i have a class destination with few properties like

```
private Set<AirTransport> airTransport;
private Set<RoadTransport> roadTransport;
private Set<TrainTransport> trainTransport;
```

since these are refrence to some other entity classes,My question is when i will fetch my destination class i don't want these refrence to get loaded in to the memory so that can fetch them later on when user click on any one of the link like (airtransport).how this can be achieve in best way.
I am ne to Hibernate so please correct me where ever i am wrong.

Thnaks in advance

Comment: don't add [closed] to your question titles. It means another thing - when a question gets closed for not being relevant to stackoverflow (or for being spam), `[closed]` is added automatically. The fact that the question is answered successfully is indicated by the accepted answer.

Comment: +1 Thnaks for the pointer..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "lazy loading". By default all collections in hibernate (and JPA) are loaded lazily - that is, they are not loaded until they are accessed. So by default your object won't fetch all the data.

But lazy loading has its complications. If you try to access a collection when the hibernate session has been closed, an exception is thrown. And as it seems you will be needing the collections after the user makes some action (clicks a button).

For that case you have two options:

- when the user clicks the button, you load the entity again, and initialize the desired collection. Either by `Hibernate.initialize(..)` or by iterating it in the view. Note that sessions are normally closed before the view is rendered, so you may need [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView)
- don't use collections at all. They have limited behaviour anyway. Use [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) or the criteria API to fetch the results. This allows you to have paging, and you are not thinking of lazy problems

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and yes agree what you said.but since my destination class will be the parent container class and which will be responsible to providing each and ever information about the destination so i think using collection is appropriate in this case. by loading entity you mean that i should put some utility methods in Destination class or something else?

Comment: well, I mean that you should fetch it again using `session.load(..)` (or `get(..)`), based on its identifier.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Lazy Fetch in ORM world. Read the tutorial [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html). You might also want to read about related pattern: [Open Session in View](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView)